# How can I present a 'standalone' View Controller ('forgetting' the previous one)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a regular `UINavigationController` with a couple of views attached, which are working perfectly fine. Its `RootViewController` has a custom Menu-button on the top left, at the same place as the "Back"-button is on the attached views. When clicking this menu-button, the menu appears and presents five options.
Obviously, by clicking one of these option, you would be presented with the ViewController for that option.

I want to completely 'forget' the current ViewController, and move on to this new controller. Usually, I would do something like `[self presentViewController....];` or `[self.navigationController push..];`, but in these methods the current ViewController will, I think, always exists 'below' the new presenting viewController (as you would return to this instantiation if using `[self dismissViewController..];`, I don't want this).

In the presenting ViewController there will be a menu-option to return back to the original controller, but I still want this to be a clean instantiation of it, and not just popping. By thinking ahead in time, I figured I would potentially create an infinite number of ViewControllers on top of each other by using the methods I know of this way.

I entered the world of iOS **after** the era of ARC began, so I have no clue how to release or deallocate such views, which I assume has relevance here.

The second View Controller is also supposed to be a root in a UINavigationController, and I'm not sure if it's best to use the same UINavigationController, or if I should present a new one, and dismiss the old. Essentially, I would like to replace the Navigation Controller's `rootViewController` **from** the `rootViewController`, but I don't see how that would be possible. Or possibly push to ViewController2, and then popping the rootViewController out of the hierarchy, leaving the new ViewController as the root, but then I assume I'd have problems with the navigational back-button(if it's even possible).

I figured it's just as easy to let ViewController2 be root at its own NavigationController, and presenting this NavigationController from ViewController1. The problem is, I want to completely remove everything that has to do with ViewController1 and its NavigationController from memory after presenting ViewController2, but I have no idea how.

I'm open to other solutions to my situation, but I'd also like an answer to how I can completely 'forget' a view after presenting another on general basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to "forget" controllers, you can just replace the window's root view controller with a new one. The original one will be deallocated if you don't have any other strong pointers to it. I'm not sure I understand all of what you're trying to do, but for example, if you want controller 1 and controller 2 to both be root view controllers of a navigation controller, and you don't want controller 1 around when you switch to 2, then do something like this from controller one:

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:second];
self.view.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

This will switch out the controllers, and controller 1 and its navigation controller will be deallocated (assuming that the only thing with a strong pointer to the navigation controller was the window, through its rootViewController property).

Comment: I did this, and used the tip from sanjaymathad's answer to put `NSLog(@"Hello");` inside the current view's `-(void)dealloc`, and it works great! However, I would like a transition to the next view instead of just **BAM**: Second view. I tried using `[self presentViewController:secondView animated:YES completion^{ self.view.window.rootViewController=secondView;}];`, which I really thought would work. Setting the secondView as root after the transition(?). Yet it seems like `secondView` is carrying a strong pointer to its "parent" somewhere, as the dealloc in firstView won't log anything now.

Comment: Actually, if I add the line `[secondView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];` in between, it deallocates, but not with any of the three other styles..

Comment: I fixed it. I wanted to use the CrossDissolve transitionStyle. I don't really know why it didn't work in the first place though.. My Navigation Controller, which I want to be root, is actually a custom `UINavigationController`, so I already have a class for it. I simply added a method in this custom navigation controller: `-(void)setAsRoot;`, which said `self.view.window.root... = self;`, and I called this method in the completion: `^{ [second setAsRoot];}`, and now the firstView deallocs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a menu `UIViewController` and add it as a root to the `UINavigationController` on launch. Add 1st `UIViewController` as a child controller to menu `UIViewController` when `viewDidLoad` of menu controller is called. When you click menu to show 2nd `UIViewController`, remove the 1st `UIViewController` from menu view controller and add 2nd `UIViewController` to child of the menu view controller. You can put `NSLog` in both, 1st and 2nd view controller's `dealloc` method to check if its released or not. Logic is like this

//inside menuvc class

```
@interface MenuVC{
     UIViewController * currentVC; // current child controller to menuVC
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [self addChildController:firstVC]; //to add view controller 1 intially
    currentVC = firstVC;
}

-(void)add2ndChildController{

    [currentVC removeFromParentViewController];
    [self addChildController:secondVC]; //to add view controller 2 when needed   
    currentVC = secondVC;
}
```

// dealloc of 1st vc

```
-(void)dealloc{

    NSLog(@"first vc released");
}
```

I just wrote some sample logic of what I explained before, you have to generalize this logic if you feel its right for you. Hope it helps :)